# How to display the selected records

Tags: sql, vb6

Using VB6

Listbox

```
checkbox EmpID

Selected 001
unSelected 002
Selected 003
....
....
```

I want to view the records belonging only to selected employees.

Query

```
Select * from table where empid = "checkbox selected employees"
```

Expected Output

```
EmpID Name Dept.

001 Rajan IT 
003 Vijayan Accounts
```

What code do I need to select multiple employees in the list box?

Comment: Why'd you remove the database and sql-query tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by building up a WHERE condition.

As the final SQL needs to be something along these lines:

```
SELECT EmpID, Name, Dept FROM Employees WHERE EmpID='001' OR EmpID='003';
```

Or, if your Database supports it:

```
SELECT EmpID, Name, Dept FROM Employees WHERE EmpID IN ('001', '003');
```

You just need to go through all your checkboxes and create the string using something like:

```
'Find each checked item
For Index = 0 to CheckListBox.ListCount - 1
  If CheckListBox.Selected(Index) Then
    'Append to an ID list string
    If IDList <> "" Then IDList = IDList & ", "
    IDList = IDList & "'" & Format(CheckListBox.ItemData(Index), "000") & "'"
  End IF
Next

'Create the final SQL statement
If IDList <> "" Then 
  Query = "SELECT EmpID, Name, Dept FROM Employees WHERE EmpID IN (" & IDList & ");"
End If
```

Being any more specific than this is difficult without knowing what Database engine and library you're using, the checkbox control structure, or the database schema.

Comment: Pardon? I'll still need that extra information before I can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: You still need to provide that information on how you've created the controls, what they are, how they're populated. Individual check boxes, a control array, a check list box, etc