# Facing difficulty in constructing SQL from multiple multi-select listboxes

Tags: oracle, vb6, listbox, multi-select

I have a form in which there are around 6 multiselect listBoxes. the listBoxes are populated from different tables.  I have no problem in storing the selections from listBoxes in variables and then using the variables in a SQL query. the variable stores the selected item from listBox as follows:

```
If clientList.SelCount > 0 Then

    For i = 0 To clientList.ListCount - 1

      If clientList.Selected(i) Then
           If Len(criteria_cl) = 0 Then
               criteria_cl = Chr(39) & clientList.List(i) & Chr(39)
      Else
         criteria_cl = criteria_cl & "," & Chr(39) & clientList.List(i) & Chr(39)
      End If

 End If
Next

 Else 
 End If
```

the SQL query is as follows with more variables which are called criteria_xx

```
 strsql = "select * from pmt_hist_dmart_step2 where dbr_portfolio in (" & criteria_pf & ") and DBR_CLIENT in (" & criteria_cl & _
 ") and DBR_ACCT_TYPE in (" & criteria_ac & ")..... ;"
```

How do I deal with a situation when the user makes no selection. Currently, the criteria_xx variable becomes blank and the IN clause contains ('') and throws an error.

Please provide some advice on how to overcome this? If it were only two or three listBoxes, I would written different queries but this is six multiselect listBoxes and I have no clue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display the selected records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951372/how-to-display-the-selected-records)

Comment: Simply omit that part of the SQL if it's blank, it will require you to make slightly more of it conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
strsql = " select *                          " &                        _
         "   from pmt_hist_dmart_step2       " &                        _
         "  where " & iif(len(criteria_pf) = 0,                         _
                          "",                                           _
                          "dbr_portfolio in (" & criteria_pf & ") and " _
                         ) &                                            _
                      iif(len(criteria_cl) = 0,                         _
                          "",                                           _
                          "DBR_CLIENT in (" & criteria_cl & ") and "    _
                         ) &                                            _
                      iif(len(criteria_ac) = 0,                         _
                          "",                                           _
                          "DBR_ACCT_TYPE in (" & criteria_ac & ") and " _
                         ) &                                            _
                      ... &                                             _
                  " 1 = 1;"
```

The idea here is that each clause of the form `dbr_portfolio in (...)` should only be included if the `...` is non-blank. `iif` is a built-in function that takes three arguments; if its first argument is `true`, then it returns its second argument, and if its first argument is `false`, then it returns its third argument. For example, `iif(1 = 1, 5, 10)` returns `5`, and `iif(1 = 2, 5, 10)` returns `10`. (N.B. The second and third arguments are both always evaluated, even though one of them is ignored afterward.)

Since something like `where and` or `and and` would not be valid SQL, I include each `and` within the `iif`-controlled code of the previous clause. Then, since a final `and` would not be valid SQL, I tacked on a final `1 = 1` clause that has no actual effect.

(By the way, sorry if my indentation scheme is ugly; it's been over a dozen years since I last wrote VB6, so I really don't remember how VB6 code is usually formatted.)